# How to create arrival rate for each lane in SUMO traffic simulation?

Tags: sumo

Provided that I have 3 lanes in 3 legged intersection. Meaning I have 9 lanes in total, I would like to have all 9 lanes having different arrival rate. Usually I am using random.py for the arrival, I am wondering if there is another method to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can define all flows manually which might be still feasible for 9 target lanes.

```
<flow id="0" from="source" to="target" begin="0" end="100" number="20" arrivalLane="0"/>
<flow id="1" from="source" to="target" begin="0" end="100" number="20" arrivalLane="1"/>
...
```

and adapt the numbers to your liking.